# Consume API with a limit

Tags: javascript, api, caching

I'm consuming an external API using AXIOS and JavaScript.

The API is limited to 10 requests per hour (in general, not per user). Once the limit is reached, an error message is returned to the user.

This all works as expected.

But of course, this is an issue as I have 100's of people trying to access the data via the website every day.

My expertise is Front End and this smells very much like Back-End work.

My initial ideas are:

1. Make a copy of the data returned from the API and save it in my own database
2. Serve this copied data to the users, this way there's no limit.

My GOTCHA is :

How do I achieve getting and then saving the data, every hour, on the server?

If this is even acceptable, how would I implement this?

Comment: Your approach sounds quite reasonable to me

Comment: Thank you. How would i do this at server level though? some sort of Cron?

Comment: The linked question shows you how, did you check it out?

Comment: sorry didn't see that. Will check it out. Thanks.